# Is it possible to pass href from <Link> through a HOC into an <a tag>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following situation
in the main component

```
<Link href={'test'}>
      <PrimaryAnchor>Welcome</PrimaryAnchor>
</Link>
```

in PrimaryAnchor component

```
const PrimaryAnchor = forwardRef(function PrimaryAnchor({ children, extraClass = '', ...props }, ref) {
    return (
        <a className={`primary-btn ${extraClass}`} {...props}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            {children}
        </a>
    )
});
```

What I want is to have the href tag from Link inside the tag from the Primary component.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: That's what the `passHref` prop in `next/link` is used for. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `ref` to the `a` element.

```
const PrimaryAnchor = forwardRef(function PrimaryAnchor({ children, extraClass = '', onClick, href }, ref) {
    return (
        <a ref={ref} onClick={onClick} href={href} className={`primary-btn ${extraClass}`}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            {children}
        </a>
    )
});
```

[RESOURCE](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component)